# USE 'database' in mysql2 fails

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql2

I want to automatically create a database and connect to it on the application start-up. To this end I use the following code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

async function setupDB() {
    const db = await mysql.createConnection({
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        decimalNumbers: true
    });

    await db.execute('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS my_db')
        .catch((err) => console.log(`Database creation failed: ${err}`));
 
    await db.execute(`USE my_db`)
        .catch((err) => console.log(`Using database failed: ${err}`));

    return db;
}
```

The execution of 'USE' command fails with the following error message:

> Using database failed: Error: This command is not supported in the
> prepared statement protocol yet

Similar code works fine without using the promise wrapper.
What is going on here?

Comment: I would be tempted to close the connection after the CREATE and reopen it with the database parameter set as per normal connection

Comment: It works, but it's a bit dirty hack.

Comment: Think you can maybe alternatively use `db.changeUser({ database: 'my_db' });`